# Can a GPO be exported from one server and imported into another?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, group-policy

I have a W2008R2 server where we have a default GPO setup. I like the setup and do not want to recreate it for our new W2012 server.

I did export it from 2008 but the only option I can find to import in 2012 GPM is manage backups. I add the directory where it was backed up to and it doesn't find anything.

Can I export/import to the new server? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first create a new GPO in the target domain that you want to import the settings into, *then* right-click it and choose **Restore from Backup...**

Another alternative is to connect your Group Policy Management Console to both domains, and then you can copy and paste GPOs between domains; just watch out for ownership of the GPOs after doing so.

The bonus to doing it that way is that will also copy scripts associated to the policy object (if the script is stored directly in the policy's folder).

> we have a default GPO setup.  I like the setup and do not want to recreate it

PS: if your talking specifically about the "Default Group Policy" object, then you are doing things wrong (and now is the perfect time to start doing them right).

You really shouldn't be modifying the "Default Group Policy" object. Instead, add other GPOs to override its defined policies as necessary.

That way if you need to revert a policy to the default setting as it was out of box, you can just disable/delete the other GPOs instead of running around trying to figure out what the "Defaults" originally were.  It also allows you to easily separate your polices into GPOs based on what they are for, so they can be applied granularly, and as needed, to various OUs.

Comment: Great info. I'll make the adjustments you suggested. Thank you!