# export a security rules in registry or gpedit and import to other systems

Tags: group-policy

I add some additional rules in software restriction policies on my windows, now  want to make a batch file or any other kind of files to export this rules and import them on another system.

I export reg keys but I can not import it because:

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects**{4AE9A665-DA8F-491B-AF10-F4BD804FA4E3}**Machine\Software\Policies\Microsoft\

machine name is different from others. can you recommend me a way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a GPO be exported from one server and imported into another?](http://superuser.com/questions/823588/can-a-gpo-be-exported-from-one-server-and-imported-into-another)

Comment: no. it's based on a domain policy. but this is not.

Comment: Applying it at domain level will mean the GP gets applied to all machines regardless of name.